# NA values when creating clusters using kmeans on my test data ser

Tags: r, k-means, na

I am new using R and I don't quite understand what is happening here so would greatly appreciate any help to understand why my kmeans cluster has NA values on my test set.

This is process I am following:

```
#1 - Load data and libraries

library(caTools)
library(caret)
library(flexclust)

train = read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#2 - Convert state vars to Factors

train$condition=as.factor(train$condition)
train$carrier=as.factor(train$carrier)
train$color=as.factor(train$color)
train$storage=as.factor(train$storage)
train$productline=as.factor(train$productline)
train$biddable=as.factor(train$biddable)
train$cellular=as.factor(train$cellular)

#3 - Split Train set to Train and Validation sets

set.seed(123)
split = sample.split(train$sold, SplitRatio = 0.7)
train = subset(train, split==TRUE)
test = subset(train, split==FALSE)

#4 - Remove redundant vars (UniqueID and description) to create clusters

trainLimit = train
testLimit = test
trainLimit$sold=NULL
testLimit$sold=NULL     

#5 - Create clusters

#5.1 - convert values to numeric

trainLimit$biddable=as.numeric(trainLimit$biddable)
trainLimit$startprice=as.numeric(trainLimit$startprice)
trainLimit$condition=as.numeric(trainLimit$condition)
trainLimit$cellular=as.numeric(trainLimit$cellular)
trainLimit$carrier=as.numeric(trainLimit$carrier)
trainLimit$color=as.numeric(trainLimit$color)
trainLimit$storage=as.numeric(trainLimit$storage)
trainLimit$productline=as.numeric(trainLimit$productline)

testLimit$biddable=as.numeric(testLimit$biddable)
testLimit$startprice=as.numeric(testLimit$startprice)
testLimit$condition=as.numeric(testLimit$condition)
testLimit$cellular=as.numeric(testLimit$cellular)
testLimit$carrier=as.numeric(testLimit$carrier)
testLimit$color=as.numeric(testLimit$color)
testLimit$storage=as.numeric(testLimit$storage)
testLimit$productline=as.numeric(testLimit$productline)

#5.2 - Normalize variable values (to reduce the dominance from start price)

preprocess=preProcess(trainLimit)
trainNorm=predict(preprocess,trainLimit)
testNorm=predict(preprocess,testLimit)

#5.3 - Create clusters

k=6
set.seed(123)
km = kmeans(trainNorm,centers=k)
km.kcca = as.kcca(km, trainNorm)
clusterTrain = predict(km.kcca)
clusterValidation = predict(km.kcca, newdata=testNorm)
```

data for testing:

```
biddable    startprice  condition   cellular    carrier color   storage productline sold
1   0.99    Used    1   Unknown White   64  iPad 1  1
0   99.99   Seller refurbished  0   None    White   16  iPad 1  0
1   20  Used    1   AT&T    Black   16  iPad 1  1
0   75  Used    0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  1
0   95  Used    0   None    Black   32  iPad 1  0
0   84.99   Seller refurbished  1   AT&T    Unknown 64  iPad 1  1
0   90  Used    0   None    Unknown 16  iPad 1  1
0   79  Used    0   None    Black   32  iPad 1  0
0   115 Used    0   None    Unknown 32  iPad 1  0
0   289.95  New 1   Unknown Black   64  iPad 1  0
0   69.99   Used    0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  0
0   269.99  New 0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  0
0   79.99   Seller refurbished  1   AT&T    Black   16  iPad 1  1
1   75  Used    0   None    Unknown 32  iPad 1  1
1   50  Used    0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  1
0   169.95  New 0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  0
1   62  Used    0   None    Black   64  iPad 1  1
0   279.95  New 0   None    Unknown 32  iPad 1  0
0   149.95  New other (see details) 1   Unknown Black   64  iPad 1  0
0   99  Seller refurbished  1   AT&T    Black   64  iPad 1  0
1   100 Used    0   None    Unknown 16  iPad 1  0
1   49.49   Used    0   None    Unknown 32  iPad 1  1
1   25  Used    1   AT&T    Unknown 16  iPad 1  1
1   40  Used    0   None    Unknown 16  iPad 1  1
1   29.99   Used    1   AT&T    Black   64  iPad 1  1
1   49.99   Used    1   AT&T    Black   16  iPad 1  1
1   50  Used    0   None    Black   16  iPad 1  1
1   80  Used    1   AT&T    Black   64  iPad 1  1
```

Any idea why this is happenning?

Comment: Try making a reproducible example, it's hard to decipher what is going on just based on snippets of your code.

Comment: Can't say much if you don't provide an example as @RomanLuštrik pointed out. On a side note, you should remove the dependent variable only from the test set (how can you fit it without ever seeing it?)

Comment: On a side note if your intention is to convert multiple columns to numeric you can have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772279/converting-multiple-columns-from-character-to-numeric-format-in-r) to do it via a simple function. On similar lines, it would be safer to convert via `as.numeric(as.character())`.