# using dplyr can we change to numeric data type only those columns for which data type is integer

Tags: r, dplyr

I wonder if there is any way to convert only those columns which are integer data types to numeric using dplyr or base package?

My dataset is something like this:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("AA0101", "AA0101", "AA0102", "AA0102", "AA0103", "AA0103"), 
               V2 = 38080:38085, 
               V3 = c(0L, 50353564L, 13000567L, 50395060L, 0L, 0L),
               V4 = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L), 
               V5 = c("PS", "NW", "PS", "NW", "PS", "NW"), 
               V6 = c("4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019", "4/1/2019"), 
               V7 = c("20:06:04", "20:22:17", "20:41:53", "21:31:04", "21:58:51", "23:08:04"), 
               V8 = c("20:06:14", "20:22:22", "20:41:58", "21:31:11", "21:59:01", "23:08:10"), 
               V9 = c(10L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 6L), 
               V10 = c("0:00:00", "20:22:22", "20:41:58", "21:31:11", "0:00:00", "0:00:00"), 
               V11 = c("0:00:00", "20:23:58","20:42:55", "21:31:31", "0:00:00", "0:00:00"), 
               V12 = c(0L, 96L, 57L, 20L, 0L, 0L), 
               V13 = c("AGENT", "AGENT", "AGENT","AGENT", "AGENT", "HANG"), 
               V14 = c("20:06:13", "20:23:57", "20:42:54", "21:31:30", "21:59:00", "0:00:00"), 
               V15 = c("20:08:07", "20:25:41", "20:43:43", "21:34:52", "22:01:03", "0:00:00"), 
               V16 = c(114L, 104L, 49L, 202L, 123L, 0L), 
               V17 = c("DORIT", "SHLOMO", "DORIT", "ZOHARI", "DORIT", "NO_SERVER")))
```

When I did:

```
 str(dat)
```

It returned me the following:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ V1 : chr  "AA0101" "AA0101" "AA0102" "AA0102" ...
 $ V2 : int  38080 38081 38082 38083 38084 38085
 $ V3 : int  0 50353564 13000567 50395060 0 0
 $ V4 : int  0 2 2 1 0 0
 $ V5 : chr  "PS" "NW" "PS" "NW" ...
 $ V6 : chr  "4/1/2019" "4/1/2019" "4/1/2019" "4/1/2019" ...
 $ V7 : chr  "20:06:04" "20:22:17" "20:41:53" "21:31:04" ...
 $ V8 : chr  "20:06:14" "20:22:22" "20:41:58" "21:31:11" ...
 $ V9 : int  10 5 5 7 10 6
 $ V10: chr  "0:00:00" "20:22:22" "20:41:58" "21:31:11" ...
 $ V11: chr  "0:00:00" "20:23:58" "20:42:55" "21:31:31" ...
 $ V12: int  0 96 57 20 0 0
 $ V13: chr  "AGENT" "AGENT" "AGENT" "AGENT" ...
 $ V14: chr  "20:06:13" "20:23:57" "20:42:54" "21:31:30" ...
 $ V15: chr  "20:08:07" "20:25:41" "20:43:43" "21:34:52" ...
 $ V16: int  114 104 49 202 123 0
 $ V17: chr  "DORIT" "SHLOMO" "DORIT" "ZOHARI" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Can do `dat <- dplyr::mutate_if(dat, is.integer, as.numeric)`, probably a duplicate

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772279/converting-multiple-columns-from-character-to-numeric-format-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `base R` we can do

```
i1 <- sapply(dat, is.integer)
dat[i1] <- lapply(dat[i1], as.numeric)
```